# Clipping is not including all parts of the input layer

Tags: qgis, clip

[image: Output of validity check]

[image]

[image: Paramaters for clipping]

[image: output of clipping]

I'm having trouble with clipping a certain layer in QGIS 3.10.13. As you can see in the 4th picture, not all of the layer is being included when clipped - only one part of the layer which is highlighted in yellow.

How can I get all of the input layer to be included in the clip?

I added a picture of the `land-use_pg` layer in the layers panel. The result of the clip is the yellow on top of the grey buffers, so it seems like when I'm clipping it is only including the 'agriculture' part of the layer instead of all of them.

I added a picture of the output of the validity check of layer 'land-use_pg'. This seems to explain why only 'agriculture' is included when clipping layer 'land-use_pg', but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I used the fix geometries tool and clipping works fine now.

Comment: How many layers are there in the second image? `land-use_pg` layer is the little green one?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm confused. I cannot tell from your second image what is incorrect.  Grey? Yellow?  Green?  Please edit your answer to separately include your input layers. Then in the output layer, please indicate what is incorrect.  Also, whenever I have problems such as yours, I always: 1) make sure that all input layers are projected to the same Coordinate Reference System, and 2) confirm that there are no geometry errors in any of the input layers with the *Check Validity* tool, and if necessary, the *Fix Geometries* tool.

Comment: Do you get `invalid geometry` error? Use "Check Validity" tool first. You will get three layers, "Error output", "Invalid output", "Valid output" and be sure that "Invalid output" layer has no any feature.  Your data is very susceptible to contain invalid geometries.